# Govern limits Salesforce Activity Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

If I inject 5000 contacts at the same time in a journey that has a Salesforce Activity. Will the triggering of this activity result in 1, 3 (2000/2000/1000) or 5000 transactions?

Or is there another scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SF Activities within JB do not batch, it will be 5000 API calls

Comment: Correct, however if the concern of OP is API limits/billing, the API calls coming through MC connector running as Connected App will not count towards the limits.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The concerns isn't about API limits. It's govern limits in Core.

Comment: are you sure @LukasLunow ? Is there any docs to show that with MC App will not count towards the limits?

Comment: @ÁtilaCastroAlves - here you go: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000340150&mode=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&type=1